# Can this function be expressed as a polynomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Consider the following function
$$
f(x_1,\dots,x_N,y_1,\dots,y_N) = \prod_{i=1}^N x_i^{y_i} \cdot (1-x_i)^{(1-y_i)}
$$
where $x_1,\dots,x_N \in [0,1]$ and $y_1,\dots,y_N \in \{0,1\}$. Because the $y_i$'s are binary, then I want to express $f$ instead as a polynomial in $x_1,\dots,x_N$ and $y_1,\dots,y_N$. That is, I want to know if it is possible to write
$$
f(x_1,\dots,x_N,y_1,\dots,y_N) = c_1\prod_{i \in I_{x}^{[1]}} x_i \cdot \prod_{j \in I_{y}^{[1]}} y_j + c_2 \prod_{i \in I_{x}^{[2]}} x_i \cdot \prod_{j \in I_{y}^{[2]}} y_j + \cdots + c_K \prod_{i \in I_{x}^{[K]}} x_i \cdot \prod_{j \in I_{y}^{[K]}} y_j
$$
where $I_{x}^{[i]}$ is a subset of the indices $\{1,\dots,N\}$ for the $i$th term in the polynomial and $I_{y}^{[i]}$ is another (possibly different) subset of the indices $\{1,\dots,N\}$ for the $i$th term in the polynomial. If the answer is "yes", then what would the values of the coefficients $c_1,\dots,c_K$ be? Also, what would the subsets $I_x^{[1]},\dots,I_x^{[K]}$ and $I_y^{[1]},\dots,I_y^{[K]}$ be?

### Context

The reason that I'm trying to do this is that the function $f$ is part of an optimization problem that I am working on, so I think that expressing it as a polynomial would be helpful in making optimizing it with respect to $x_1,\dots,x_N$ easier.

Comment: My intuition is that it is possible, but what's the point? And have you tried anything?

Comment: @Andrew I've added some context at the end of my question.

Comment: Given that your functions are defined on different spaces, do you mean for them to agree on their intersection? If so, $f = \prod [x_iy_i + (1-x_i)(1-y_i) ] $ works.

Comment: By $M$, do you mean $N$?

Comment: @CalvinLin thanks. I was interested more in a summation rather than a product, but I guess that this is too difficult to compute.

Comment: @ElectricShadow yes, fixed.

Comment: Have you considered instead optimizing the $\log$, which would transform the product to a sum?

Comment: @RobPratt that is a good idea. However, I failed to mention in my question that $f(x_1,\dots,x_N,y_1,\dots,y_N)$ appears inside a summation, so applying the $\log$ wouldn't work because I can't move it inside. Another approach that I tried is to use the change of variables $a_i = \log(x_i)$ and $b_i = \log(1-x_i)$, which would lead to a log-sum-exp expression that is convex. Unfortunately, the challenge with this approach is that the constraints form a non-convex set. This approach led to my question [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/11294/7263), where $f$ is the log-sum-exp function.

Comment: Have you tried this for N=2 or 3?

Comment: @martycohen yes, but I didn't see a clear pattern, which is why I'm wondering if there is one in the first place.